# Algorithm to find least number of trades between people

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been thinking about this question for a while now.

Let's say there is a list `s` that contains books that people are selling. I have a book in `s`, and I want to trade for a book that is in `s` (something I don't have).

Each person in this scenario is selling one book in `s`, and also wants one book that is in `s`.

Is there an algorithm to find out the least number of trades required between people to get the book that I want (and give my book to people who want it)?

Please tell me if this seems confusing (because it probably is).

Thanks for answering the question!

EDIT: List `s` can grow at any time.

Comment: I think it might also depend on how many people are there and what books they already have or want... can you provide that as well?

Comment: Yes, your question is confusing.  You'll also probably get dinged for not making an attempt to solve this problem on your own.  Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that no two people are selling the same book and no two people want the same book? (In other words: is it guaranteed that there's a way to swap all the books and have everyone end up with the book they want?)

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output examples?

Comment: @ruakh that is not guaranteed. Sometimes, there wouldnt be any trades possible.

Comment: @BrentR what part is confusing? And the reason I have not made an attempt is because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you the only person in the group who's willing to temporarily hold an unwanted book? What determines whether a person is willing to trade a book that they don't want in the hopes of eventually getting the book they want?

Comment: How do they trade? Is there any cost price or selling price to the book? Because otherwise, just exchange.

Comment: @vivek_23 there are no prices or anything like that attached to the book. Assume that all possible exchanges between people can actually happen, but I want the least amount of exchanges to take place so that I get the book I want

Comment: @mypetlion Assume no one, not even me, is willing to hold an unwanted book for a long period of time. The only time people will hold an unwanted book is if they can trade it right away for the book they want.

Comment: @GauthamRajesh an example of input and output would be better

Comment: Please define "trade" -- two people swapping their books?

Comment: @Prune yes, that is what I mean by a trade.

Comment: Can multiple people be offering the same book?  For instance, can there be three copies of "The Silmarillion" in `s`?  Credit to @btilly for this point.

Comment: @Prune yes, multiple people can sell the same book. Multiple people can also want the same book, for that matter.

Comment: @GauthamRajesh: Thanks; that deflates my answer entirely.  Correcting my answer makes it equivalent to the first one, so I'm deleting it.

Comment: @Prune Actually if you look above, ruakh noticed the same point first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn this into a graph as follows.  Books are the nodes of the graph.  You have a directed edge from book A to book B if someone in S is offering book B and wants book A.  You are looking for the shortest path from the book that you have to the book that you really want.

The shortest path can be discovered by a breadth-first search.  You can implement one as follows:

```
todo = [starting_book]
path = {starting_book: None}
while len(todo) and target_book not in path:
    book = list.pop(0)
    for next_book in neighbors(book):
        if next_book not in path:
            path[next_book] = book
            todo.append(next_book)
if target_book in path:
    solution = [target_book]
    while solution[-1] != starting_book:
        solution.append(path[solution[-1]])
else:
    solution = None
```

Note, the solution that I am offering here gives the set of book trades to happen, but not the people.  Turning a particular book trade back into the person to talk to can be done either by searching `s` or with a lookup table.

This is also not an online solution - keeping track of shortest paths as things are added to/removed from `s` is going to be a lot of work.

Comment: This is a good solution. Is there any way to implement it in java?

Comment: @GauthamRajesh See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/ for a Java implementation of breadth first search.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This answer assumes you want everyone to have their desired book at the end of the day. Other answer(s) address the case where all you care about is obtaining *your* desired book.

I believe this is equivalent to the minimum number of swaps to sort an array. Number the books 1 to N, and number the people 1 to N such that person *i* wants book *i*. Now we have an array like:

```
Book:    2  1  4  3
Person:  1  2  3  4
```

i.e. Person 1 has book 2, person 2 has book 1, etc. Now a trade is just a swap in this array, so we just want the minimum number of swaps to sort the array. [This is a known problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/).

If you can have more than one person selling a given book, or more than one person who wants a given book, you'd have to make sure that for each book, the number of people who want it equals the number of people selling it, otherwise there's no solution. Then, just use multiple copies of the book in the "book" array, again sorting people by the numeric value of the book they want. For example, let's say we have 4 people and 2 books, where two people want book 1 and two people want book 2; we'd have:

```
Book:    2  2  1  1
Person:  1  2  3  4
```

Again, we want to sort the "book" array in the fewest number of swaps.

Comment: Nice solution! :)

Comment: It isn't equivalent.  You are not looking to sort the whole array.  Just to find a minimal chain from any copy of a book that you want to yourself, and everyone else can go hang.  (The fact that multiple people can have a particular book also is an important wrinkle.)

Comment: @btilly Oh, I misunderstood the question in that case (in my defense though, it is worded in a confusing way). I'll make a note of that, but will keep this answer since it may still be useful, and the other answer references it.

Comment: @arshajii I am sorry for making the question confusing, although that wasn't my intention.

Comment: The post you're linking to uses a different concept of "swap", which is not switching two elements of the array. The answers there aren't applicable to this problem.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good and makes sense (I upvoted it), but I will make @btilly's answer the accepted one because his answer applies more to my case.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, fixed.